# On form submition websites css shows up on the page

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Here is the image[image]

i made this while following https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions. I don't know what could be wrong. I have searched far and wide even as far as going into svelte discord.. nothing i hope someone can help me

+page.svelte

```html
<form method="POST" action="?/login">
    <label>
      Email
      <input name="email" type="email">
    </label>
    <label>
      Password
      <input name="password" type="password">
    </label>
    <button>Log in</button>
  </form>

  <style>
    :root {
        --border-color: #c0c0c0;
        --border-width: 1px;
    }


    form {
        padding: 20px;

        border: var(--border-width) solid var(--border-color);
        border-radius: 10px;

        background-color: #F6F8FA;
        width: 15%;

        margin-top: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

+page.server.js

```js
import { fail } from '@sveltejs/kit';

/** @type {import('./$types').Actions} */
export const actions = {
    login: async ({ cookies, request }) => {
        const data = await request.formData();
        const email = data.get("email"); // Either username or an email
        const password = data.get("password");

        if (!email) {
            return fail(400, { email, missing: true });
        }
        if (!password) {
            return fail(400, { password, missing: true });
        }

        return { success: true }
    }
  };
```